# Immediately register and transfer domain for hosting for .NET

Tags: .net, hosting, dns

I'm doing a ASP.NET/SQL Server contract project. The client wants to show what's built so far  to demo it for some third-party on a domain that's currently unregistered.

Normally I register domain names through GoDaddy. But GoDaddy puts a lock for 60 days on your domain after its registered, so I'd have to get GoDaddy hosting too to demo it.

I'd like to know if all registrars do this locking. I'd like to register the domain right now, but have the freedom to have it hosted by tomorrow using a different company.

Is this going to be possible? Can I register the domain with someone today and transfer it to a different company for hosting before the demo tomorrow?

Any recommendations? Thanks!

EDIT: So I should be able to register the domain with one company, set up hosting WITHOUT transfering the domain, and just edit the DNS entries with the registrar to point at the hosting company?

I thought the lock prevented me from doing that, but sounds like the lock was probably just for the transfer--not the DNS changes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why do you need to have the domain registered with the same company you're hosting with? Can't you just change the DNS settings with GoDaddy to point to the hosted site? I'm not familiar with GoDaddy, but it'd be poor if they don't allow this.

Comment: I could be wrong, but last time I tried, I believe this 60 day lock prevented me from changing the DNS entries. But maybe I tried to transfer the domain to the hosting company instead of just point the DNS to the hosting company.

Comment: 60 day locks on transferring the domain are common. I'd double-check the DNS stuff and, if you can't change it, drop them an email. I've not seen a registrar that prevents this before (although I wouldn't be surprise to hear they exist :-( ...).

Answer (score 1):

No all registrars do not do this locking. GoDaddy is pretty mean when it comes to terms of service. I hosted with them once and made a website that needed to run some task in a separate thread (in ASP.Net). I created it and it ran for 2 weeks, then they put a lock on the facility and my thread was choked. It was hell for quite a while. I shifted to a different host.

You can probably use resellerclub. I bought a reseller account with them and now have many domains. I don't do if they do retail domain selling though.

Good Luck.

EDIT: I also realized that the locking could only be on Domain name transfer to another regsitrar (I.e. if you needed to change registrars (not hosting), you can only do it after 60 days. Yes, most registrars do that.

Answer (score 0):

The lock only applies to transferring the domain or changing the ownership.  It does NOT affect DNS in any way.

Answer (score 0):

GoDaddy tells you you "opted-in" for the 60 day lock which is absolutely untrue.  Get your stuff over to a good service like NameCheap who will not voluntarily try to mess with their customers.  Even after telling GoDaddy I needed to transfer a domain they ignored me and didn't point me to a single screenshot or document which I have 'voluntarily" opted-in.  A ton of time has been wasted dealing with them.